# How to get value and record count of elements from array column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following table in Postgres:

```sql
CREATE TABLE movies (
    id serial primary key,
    title text,
    actor_ids bigint[]
)
```

How can I get the number of movies each actor has starred in? I should be printed like this:

```sql
actor_id | count
----------------
53       | 4
92       | 13
132      | 1
1221     | 2
```

The actor_ids column is an array that contains the ids of the actors starring in the movie.

Comment: Right, deleted the comment. Didn't register the bit about the array.

Comment: Yeap, it's fine. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first unnest the array, then you can apply a group by and count

```
select a.actor_id, count(*)
from movies m
  cross join unnest(m.actor_ids) as a(actor_id)
group by a.actor_id
order by a.actor_id;
```

Comment: This did the job just right, Thanks a lot! I thought it would be something unnest. Have a good one!